# Define a table type parameter

Tags: sql-server

I just try to create a table type parameter called "ListOfName", and set a parameter of such type in my procedure. But an error incurred:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Table_Name_List"

But I declare

```
 CREATE TYPE ListOfName AS TABLE (Table_Name nvarchar(50) );

 CREATE PROCEDURE spTest 
    @Table_Name_List    ListOfName   READONLY

 AS
    SELECT * from dbo.Table_Size_Daily

    WHERE    Table_NAME IN (@Table_Name_List) 
 Go
```

If I add a statement before the definition chunk,

```
 DECLARE @Table_Name_List  AS ListOfName;
```

The error was:

> The variable name '@Table_Name_List' has already been declared.
>   Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored
>   procedure.

How can I fix it? Thanks a lot

Comment: `@Table_Name_List` is a table type not a parameter to pass in your `where`

Comment: study [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to use Table Types

Comment: quick fix: `WHERE Table_NAME IN (SELECT Table_Name FROM @Table_Name_List) `

Comment: Thank you very much @techspider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that there is misconception on what a Table Type is.  Even though there is only one column in your table type, you can't treat that as a single-column argument.

> Consider a Table type parameter as any other table irrespective of
>   number of columns you have.

In order to fix your issue, I would prefer your `WHERE` condition to change as below:

```
WHERE Table_NAME IN (SELECT Table_Name FROM @Table_Name_List)
```

However, I would strongly recommend you to read a few tutorials on Table type before you proceed with any implementation.  For ex: [This Table Valued Parameters article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN gives clear insight into it.